# Shorten JavaScript ternary

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I use a ternary expression like this all the time, but I don't like the null in it. Is there a terser way to do this?

```
var_1 === 'yes' ? var_2=true : null;
```

This is a simplified version of what it is I am doing. I just want to check if something is true/false then do something otherwise do nothing(so I put null in). Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why use the conditional operator here at all? This seem like it should be a simple `if`

Comment: Really, it isn't correct to do assignments in a ternary anyways. Ternarys should be used to evaluate to a value, then *that* value is assigned. Just use a full `if`, then this is a non-problem.

Comment: please add what you really want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean:

```
var_2 = var_1 === 'yes' ? true : null
```

You can also use the syntax

```
var_2 = var_1 === 'yes' && true
```

will set `var_2 = true` if `var_1 = 'yes'` otherwise `var_2 = false`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use `var_2 = var_1 === 'yes';` as it works for all type like `yes`, `undefined`, `null`, `''` and `0`.

```js
//when var_1 is 'yes'
var var_1 = 'yes';
var var_2 = var_1 === 'yes';
console.log(var_2);

//when undefined
var_1 = undefined;
var_2 = var_1 === 'yes';
console.log(var_2);

//when null
var_1 = null;
var_2 = var_1 === 'yes';
console.log(var_2);

//when blank
var_1 = '';
var_2 = var_1 === 'yes';
console.log(var_2);

//when 0
var_1 = 0;
var_2 = var_1 === 'yes';
console.log(var_2);
```

Comment: but `var_2` gets a new value if the condition is `false`, which shouldn't.

Comment: @NinaScholz yes it does and I believe that should still be fine if OP want to use that value further as `null` and `false` can be used interchangeably

Comment: op is takling about `null` as value for the third part ternary, not as value for `var_2`, as i understand the question. for me, it looks like, if the condition is false, then the variable `var_2` should stay unchanged.

Comment: @NinaScholz I partially agree with you. Based on what OP has in question the intention seem to change the value of `var_2`. Let's wait for the input of OP.

Answer (score 0):

Can var_2 be `false`? If so:

```
var_2 = var_1 === "yes";
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlucky, there is no something like this, but maybe something like this will work for you:

`var1 === 'yes' && var_2 = true`

If argument before `&&` is `true` than argument after `&&` is also called and executed, otherwise only argument before is called and executed.

It is not clean way, but I sometimes use it.

Answer (score 0):

The most correct way would be to check the condition and take that `true` result or if `false` use the original value as default for assignment.

That means the original value stays if the condition is `false`.

```
var2 = var1 === 'yes' || var2;
```